# Difference between SE and 95% CI?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, lme4-nlme, predictive-models, mean

I have results using the SE of the estimated marginal means calculated from the linear mixed model (lmer in R). I was told to use the within-subject 95% CI instead. To what extent does it matter if I use one over the other? Wouldn't the model predictions be more accurate? Does anyone have a good reference that would explain the benefits of using the standard error as predicted by the estimated marginal means over the 95% CI (or vice versa). Or, a reference to indicate that there is no benefit of one over the other?

Comment: The model predictions are whatever they are: their accuracy doesn't depend on how you choose to report it!

Comment: That's what I thought. Basically, I am being told to use 95% CI instead for SO many graphs that I already created with SE. If it doesn't matter how I report it, then I don't want to change it just because another person likes 95% CI better. If there is a difference (either direction), then some literature to reference would be helpful. @whuber

Comment: It's a matter of visual perception, of conventions, and of nuances in the message you are trying to convey to the audience -- as well as how much power the person making this request holds over you.  Often it is wise to accede to such requests from peer reviewers and usually there's no option when they are thesis advisors.  Since graphics frequently have to be redone (for various reasons), it's always prudent to plan for that and automate the process as much as possible.  If you haven't, then this is your opportunity to do so!

Comment: Thanks @whuber ! I appreciate the helpful insights.

Comment: If you are plotting the estimate and then 1 se on either side then you are plotting a confidence interval, a 68% one. It is a slightly eccentric choice of confidence coefficient.